# Validating list of email extention set as JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

How can I validate user inputted email and check their extension with a list of email extensions in a JSON?

Like if I type abc@efg.com its going to check only the email extension which is @efg.com in a list of JSON.

OR a regex that will only get the values after "@" and ignore anything before that.

```
[
    {
        "School": "Ivy Tech Community College",
        "Email": "ivytech.edu"
    },
    {
        "School": "Liberty University",
        "Email": "liberty.edu"
    },
    {
        "School": "Miami Dade College",
        "Email": "mdc.edu"
    },
    {
        "School": "Lone Star College",
        "Email": "lonestar.edu"
    },
    {
        "School": "Ashford University",
        "Email": "ashford.edu"
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? Why not just split the email string by `@` and get the latter part from that?

Comment: BTW, it's called a domain, not an extension. Extensions are the ends of filenames, like `.jpg` and `.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of regex, you can iterate through the array of schools, and match the domain like this:

```
var schools = [
    {"School":"Ivy Tech Community College","Email":"ivytech.edu"},
    {"School":"Liberty University","Email":"liberty.edu"},
    {"School":"Miami Dade College","Email":"mdc.edu"},
    {"School":"Lone Star College","Email":"lonestar.edu"},
    {"School":"Ashford University","Email":"ashford.edu"}
]

function validate(email) {
    var domain = email.split('@').pop();
    for(var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
        if(domain === schools[i].Email) return schools[i].School;
    }

    return 'Domain Not Found';
}
```

You can replace `schools[i].School` with `true` and `'Domain Not Found'` with `false` to just check with it exists.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/gwhkq520/

Answer (score 2):

```
// initial data
var data = '[ {"School":"Ivy Tech Community College","Email":"ivytech.edu"},' + '{"School":"Liberty University","Email":"liberty.edu"},' + '{"School":"Miami Dade College","Email":"mdc.edu"},' + '{"School":"Lone Star College","Email":"lonestar.edu"},' + '{"School":"Ashford University","Email":"ashford.edu"} ]';

// json-ify our data
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

// map the values of each JSON 'Email' property from jsonData in an array 
var emailsArray = jsonData.map(function (x) { return x.Email; });

// email address for testing
var testEmail = "john@liberty.edu";

// split the email address by the "@" character and use the second part (domain)
if (arrayContains(testEmail.split("@")[1], emailsArray))
{
    // this will fire as john@liberty.edu matches liberty.edu in emailsArray
    console.log("emailsArray contains domain");
}
else
{
    console.log("emailsArray does not contain domain");
}

// function to check if an item is contained in an array
function arrayContains(item, array)
{
    return (array.indexOf(item) > -1);
}
```

Complete JSFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nhr9r09y/1/).

Notes:

- you can ignore the first two lines of code as I'm guessing you're getting your JSON data from a web response
- an assumption is being made that `testEmail` adheres to the format of an email address; you might need to implement some kind of validation to verify that the string being input is an actual email
- we split `testEmail` by the `@` character and get the second part of the result (which will be at index 1, since arrays are zero-based) using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- the `emailsArray` array is created using the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function
- `arrayContains` uses the [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method to check if `testEmail` exists in `emailsArray`

I think I've clarified what every line of code in the example does. You can now take it and adjust it to your own requirements—and even better, improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like trashrOx mentioned would work:

```
var edus = [
    {"School":"Ivy Tech Community College","Email":"ivytech.edu"},
    {"School":"Liberty University","Email":"liberty.edu"},
    {"School":"Miami Dade College","Email":"mdc.edu"},
    {"School":"Lone Star College","Email":"lonestar.edu"},
    {"School":"Ashford University","Email":"ashford.edu"}
];

var emails = ['matty.fake@lonestar.edu','himom@mdc.edu','randomguy@yahoo.com'];

emails.forEach(function(element,index) {
  var domain = element.substring(element.indexOf('@') + 1);
  var match = 'none';
  if (domain) {
    edus.forEach(function(element,ind) {
      if (element.Email === domain) {
        match = element.School;
      }
    });
    console.log(element + ' matched ' + match);
  }
});

// matty.fake@lonestar.edu matched Lone Star College
// himom@mdc.edu matched Miami Dade College
// randomguy@yahoo.com matched none
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.some()` if you only want to validate.

some() executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some() returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

```js
var schools = [
    {"School":"Ivy Tech Community College","Email":"ivytech.edu"},
    {"School":"Liberty University","Email":"liberty.edu"},
    {"School":"Miami Dade College","Email":"mdc.edu"},
    {"School":"Lone Star College","Email":"lonestar.edu"},
    {"School":"Ashford University","Email":"ashford.edu"}
]

function validate(email) {
    var domain = email.split('@').pop();
    return schools.some(function(school) {
     return school.Email === domain;
    });
}

validate('test@ashford.edu');
```